# cmake link glew header file

Tags: c++, cmake, glew

I'm trying to add an external library to my project using CMake (v 3.10.1)

I want the libs to live in a specific directory because I like to keep it as clean as possible

My project structure looks like that

```
Project
   |
   |-- main.cpp
   |-- CMakeLists.txt (top lvl)
   |
   |-- libs/
         |
         | -- glew-1.13.0
         | -- CMakeLists.txt (lib lvl)
```

Top lvl CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (myproject)
add_executable(myproject main.cpp)

add_subdirectory (libs)
```

Lib lvl CMakeList.txt

```
### GLEW ###

include_directories(
    glew-1.13.0/include/
)

set(GLEW_SOURCE
    glew-1.13.0/src/glew.c
)

set(GLEW_HEADERS
)

add_library( GLEW_1130 STATIC
    ${GLEW_SOURCE}
    ${GLEW_INCLUDE}
)

target_link_libraries(GLEW_1130
  ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
  ${EXTRA_LIBS}
)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>


int main() {

    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`<GL/glew.h> headerfile not found`

What am I' missing in my case so that I can use the glew header files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effect of `include_directories` is **not global**: being performed from `libs/CMakeLists.txt`, it doesn't affect on *top-level* `CMakeLists.txt`.

You may "attach" include directories to the library *target*:

```
# In libs/CMakeLists.txt
target_include_directories(GLEW_1130 PUBLIC glew-1.13.0/include/)
```

so futher linking with that library as *target*:

```
# In CMakeLists.txt
target_link_libraries(myproject GLEW_1130)
```

will automatically propagate its include directories to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `add_subdirectory` third party projects into your own build system, otherwise it will pollute your configurations. One reasonable approach here is to install GLEW on your system, and use `find_package` in order to include it as part of your project:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (myproject)
find_package(glew 1.13.0)
add_executable(myproject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myproject GLEW::glew)
```