# Multiple Cmake files and SFML "fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, sfml

I've got 2 CMakeLists.txt files in my project.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Game)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(core)
add_subdirectory(core)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} game/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Core)
```

core/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(Core)    
set(SOURCE_FILES ecs/Component.hpp ecs/Destroyable.hpp ecs/Destroyable.cpp ecs/Entity.hpp ecs/Entity.cpp Game.cpp Game.hpp components/Sprite.hpp components/Sprite.cpp components/Transform.hpp components/Transform.cpp ecs/Serializable.hpp ecs/ComponentsCreator.cpp ecs/ComponentsCreator.hpp common/Utility.cpp common/Utility.hpp common/Logger.hpp common/Logger.cpp common/Vector2.hpp common/Vector2.cpp components/Camera.cpp components/Camera.hpp ecs/Component.cpp components/AnimationPlayer.cpp components/AnimationPlayer.hpp Animation.cpp Animation.hpp Frame.cpp Frame.hpp lib/termcolor.hpp lib/json.hpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/")
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

And I'm getting this error while compiling "core/ecs/Entity.hpp:3:29: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory". Could someone take a look and tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake link glew header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994121/cmake-link-glew-header-file)

Comment: BTW, instead of `link_libraries` it should be `target_link_libraries`: you need to link target, marked with first argument, with libraries in other arguments. But the command you currently use links all futher targets (created **after** the command) with libraries-arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your script won't work this way, it's most likely broken due to you calling `project()` more than once.

The stuff inside `core` is handled as a standalone project, so the include directories etc. inside are never applied to your root.

Remove the first line `project(Core)` from the second file and define the target directly as `Core`. After that it should work, unless I've missed something else.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how do I "define the target directly as Core"?